# VBA: DOWNLOAD DATA FROM HTTPS

Tags: vba, url, https, download

I want to copy all data from this https:

https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone,timeselector,filters&countries=29,32,27,37,72,22,17,10,35,7,125,26,4,5&calType=day&timeZone=7&lang=1

And paste it in excel. This is, create a code VBA, which open that link, copy all the content and paste in a worksheet. I was thinking something as:

```
 Sub DownloadFile()

 Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone,timeselector,filters&countries=29,32,27,37,72,22,17,10,35,7,125,26,4,5&calType=day&timeZone=7&lang=1"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

WinHttpReq.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A20").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

But it isn't working. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks by your help!

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT US?!?!

Comment: @rory.ap FEEL FREE TO EDIT THE TITLE.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the page retrieval. It also doesn't have a `.Select` method. What information are you trying to retrieve from the page?

Comment: Create a code VBA, which open that link (https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone,timeselector,filters&countries=29,32,27,37,72,22,17,10,35,7,125,26,4,5&calType=day&timeZone=7&lang=1), copy all the content and paste it in a worksheet. Thanks by your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the entire table to the clipboard using the `outerHTML` of the table element then write out to the sheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com/?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone,timeselector,filters&countries=29,32,27,37,72,22,17,10,35,7,125,26,4,5&calType=day&timeZone=7&lang=1", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText .querySelector("#ecEventsTable").outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?